# How to filter a list with JavaScript? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, development

I have a list named `childribbon` and in the new form of this list I have added the same list which is being displayed in display form,
[image]

If I set the `Employee` to `Nderon Hiseni` in my `childribbon` new fort

I want only items with `Nderon Hiseni` to be displayed in my `childribbon` display form?

How Can I do this with javascript?

Comment: Use sharepoint rest api or jsom to get the filtered items.

Comment: How Can I make this?

Comment: Can you explain me because I am new to sharepoint!

Comment: Does Employee field show the title from the lookup field?

Comment: No Employee field is looked up by another list column

Answer (score 1):

If this is one webpage then you can

- Add an onchange eventhandler on the drop down <select>
- Then use a JS standard `document.querySelector` to find the matching elements in the list
- You then loop all elements, find the parent TR row, and hide

Something like: *disclaimer: didn't not test this code, you are on your own*

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('onchange', function () {
    var employeeName = this.value;
    var matches = document.querySelector("a[href*=" + employeeName + "']");
    matches.forEach(function (match) {
        var row = GetAncestor(match, 'TR');
        row.style.display='none';
    });
});
```

- GetAncestor is provided by SharePoint
- You have to add `...display='block'` yourself to show rows again
- forEach might need a Polyfill in older IE versions

Answer (score -1):

Sharepoint rest api example if Employee is a lookup field and it displays the Title

```
var url= "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('childribbon')/Items?"+
           "$select=ID,Title,Employee/Title,Skills"+
           "&$expand=Employee&$filter=Employee/Title eq 'Nderon Hiseni'";
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Otherwise, if Employee is not a lookup field then the url should be

```
var url= "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('childribbon')/Items?"+
           "$select=ID,Title,Title,Skills"+
           "&$filter=Employee eq 'Nderon Hiseni'";
```

You can read this article for better understanding http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Comment: I want it to be dynamically not static, I have set a cookie with can I use that cookie to display user?

Comment: write a function and pass a variable which contains the employee name. Then call ajax with the variable